# Subprocess module error while running in Automator

Tags: python, subprocess, automator

I am running a python script with the subprocess module in the Run Shell Script block of Automator.

The code looks as follows:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['ls -a'])
```

I keep on getting an error whenever I run the workflow. The error says "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory," but no previous answers on SO have talked about this specific instance of the error. I have also tried running the code with os.system, and it works correctly.

The error looks like:
[image: OSError]

Comment: Separate each argument in your list: `['ls', '-a']`

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you. It's been a while since I used the subprocess module. I completely forgot about that part.